# What type of rear derailer can I use

Tags: derailleur

I bought a used frame without a derailer.  What type will I be able to use?  I would like to switch to trigger shifters and a good quality derailer.  See photos.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Concur on the duplicate.  @paul don't take it personally that this question gets closed as a dupe - but the answer on the other question describes exactly the claw-hanger you need.   I'm guessing the PO of this frame used an Internal gear hub, or a singlespeed setup cos I can see where the wheel nut has bitten into the frame.